# How to read a csv file synchronously and return a value from it using javascript

Tags: javascript, filereader, synchronous

I am passing in a full state name through a function called findAbbreviation(fullName) 
Im using a csv file of fullname, abbreviation pairs to return the value of the abbreviation that matches the fullname. 
What is the best way to do this, given that I want the read through of the csv to be synchronous?

d3.csv("candy.csv", function(csv) {

```
//reformat the locations to have a consistent format
//every entry in q5 is changed to an abbreviation of 2 letters
//the abbreviation lists are in the folder named such
var updatedAbbr = csv.map(function(d) {

    //check to see the entry has a value
    if (d.Q5_STATE != null) {

        //the country is the united States
        if (d.Q4_COUNTRY == "United States") {

            //if the state value is longer than two characters, set it to UU
            if (d.Q5_STATE.length > 2) {
                d.Q5_STATE = findAbbreviation(d.Q5_STATE);  
            }

            //pass through and check that the new value is not null
            if (d.Q5_STATE != null) {
                console.log(d.Q5_STATE);    
            }


        }
    }
});
```

});

function findAbbreviation(fullName) {

}

I'd like to pass in the value Alabama and get AL. Or California -> CA.

Comment: It is not clear from your question where you would get the translation from full name to abbreviation from. You write you get it from the CSV, but you are parsing that CSV so why you need a function call? Are you talking about *another* CSV? Could you add to your question a sample of the data set(s), and what your input/output expectations are with a concrete example based on that sample data?

Answer (score 0):

`d3.csv` is asynchronous, you can't do anything about that.

You could use `XMLHttpRequest` to make a synchronous request (**Danger**: This feature is deprecated) and then feed the result through `d3.csv.parse`.

I recommend embracing asynchronous programming instead.

Comment: How would I update the state value from the full name to the abbreviation using asynchronous programming?

Comment: @user2540820 —The code you have in the question appears to do that. You just don't do anything with it afterwards.

Comment: No matter what I do (global variable setting, adding delays, creating separate functions) the value for the state is never set correctly. Is there some synchronous way to read through a csv file and return a value that satisfies a conditional statement?

Comment: Right, thank you for your help. I'm just lost about how to get the right value at the right time using async programming.